# How to operate on custom HTML with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

let's say I have

```
str = "hello, <b>my name is</b> jQuery.";
```

And I want to use $ selector, to get the "my name is". What should I do?
So far I tried this:

```
html = $.parseHTML( str );
$( $(html), "b")
```

Without much success...

It only returns an array of all elements, but not the chosen element...

EDIT: I cannot modify str.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to solve with regexp

```
var str = "hello, <b class='needsThing'>my name is</b> jQuery.";
var reg = new RegExp(/<b>.*<\/b>/)
result = str.match(reg)
```

Is it, what u want?

Comment: Ok, so, can u tell what exactly u have on input, and what u need on output in example pls, @Novellizator

Comment: I have a given input and I want to get "my name is" as an output.

Comment: yeah, in the end I did it with reexps, but I thought doing it with jQuery would be more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery selector find element always add first, try this code

```
str = "hello, <b>my name is</b> jQuery.";
html = $.parseHTML( str );
$('b' ,$(html))
```

OR
you can create Empty dom element and put content inside element after that you can operate that DOM as per your requirement

```
var str = "hello, <b>my name is</b> jQuery.";
$('<div/>', {html: str}).find('b').html();
//or other short variant
$('>b', $('<div/>', {html: str})).html()
```

Comment: for some weird reason it doesnt work :( still returns undefined.  Ok to be more precise, lets say the HTML is here https://instagram.com/p/aye83DjauH/ and the selector is "meta"

Comment: you have not clear in question, if string has parent tag them you can direct manipulate don without tag, like `$(str)`

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the <b> tag an id and then get it by using jQuery.

```
str = "hello, <b  id="id">my name is</b> jQuery.";

$("#id").val();
```

Hope this helps.